# foreman assign mutiple hosts to a config group

Tags: puppet, foreman

On foreman 1.6.0 is it possible to easily assign multiple hosts to a config group (Under the Configure->Puppet->Config Groups menu)?

I've had a pretty good look around the web interface and hammer cli but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a GUI way of doing it, though you could assign config groups to a host group and assign multiple hosts to that via the host list (Hosts > All hosts, tickboxes, Select Action > Change Group).

You're right in that we're missing config group support in the CLI too, which surprised me.  I've filed [#7520](http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/7520) to fix that.

Probably the best way for now is via the REST API.  Here's an example to update just the one host, but obviously you can put this in a simple shell loop and do much more with it.

(I like to pipe the curl output through json_reformat, very handy if you have it installed.)

First you may want to get a list of config groups, or do it via the GUI:

```
$ curl -k -u admin:password https://localhost/api/v2/config_groups
```

Now you can fetch an individual host and see which config groups are already assigned:

```
$ curl -k -u admin:password https://localhost/api/v2/hosts/foreman.example.com
...
"config_groups": [
]
```

So nothing's there right now.

Here I update the host's associated config groups with an array of names ("test" in this instance):

```
$ curl -k -u admin:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"host":{"config_group_names":["test"]}}' -X PUT https://localhost/api/v2/hosts/foreman.example.com
$ curl -k -u admin:password https://localhost/api/v2/hosts/foreman.example.com
...
"config_groups": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "created_at": "2014-09-18T10:34:58Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-09-18T10:52:39Z",
        "puppetclasses": [

        ]
    }
]
```

You can also use IDs:

```
{"host":{"config_group_ids":[2, 3, 5, 7]}}
```

So putting that together you could do something like:

```
for h in a.example.com b.example.com c.example.com; do
  curl -k -u admin:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT \
    -d '{"host":{"config_group_names":["Base", "Web server"]}}' \
    https://localhost/api/v2/hosts/${h}
done
```

Comment: Awesome! hope to see this feature in a later version. Thank!

Comment: Ok so one thing that I seem to have found which is a bit of a downer, I have to pull each host in a loop to check for a config group, there doesn't seem to be a json way to pull a list of what hosts belong to the config groups :(

Comment: It's possible to search for hosts with a particular config group: https://localhost/api/v2/hosts?search=config_group=Base (any search you can do in the UI search boxes will work in the API)

Comment: Oh wow! Your some sort of wizard aren't you! That's perfect!